# Lightning networks revocable commitments: unilaterally closing could cause funds lost forever?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, multi-signature, lightning-network

If I understands correctly, A and B will exchange their revocation key once they are ready to move to the next state. What happens if B received the revocation key and decided to close the channel unilaterally *without* broadcasting the transaction. This way B can never get his funds, but A can never get his funds as well. Because A can not broadcast his transaction since B has his revocation key. Isn't it a huge risk for A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if B received the revocation key and decided to close the channel unilaterally without broadcasting the transaction

By definition, channels are only closed once a commitment transaction or the closing transaction is broadcast. So B cannot close the channel; he simply withholds data from A.

---

Your scenario is not possible because A will only give B the revocation key once both B has given A his new commitment transaction. So if B refuses to give A the revocation key to his commitment transaction, then A can close the channel by broadcast the previous commitment transaction which has not yet been revoked.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't it be unfair for B if A gets the new commitment, so he can broadcast both the old commitment and the new commitment? (especially in the case when the old commitment favors A).

Comment: The protocol is actually a bit more nuanced. A first sends B B's new commitment. When B accepts it, he has to send both the revocation key and A's new commitment before A sends B his revocation key. So if B refuses to send A the revocation key, A can close the channel unilaterally using the previous commitment which has not yet been revoked. I revised my answer slightly.

Comment: I suggest that you read this section of the lightning rfs: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md#normal-operation